# How do I get values from an array of json objects based on a condition in golang?

Tags: go

I have an array like this.

```
[{
    "seq" : 2,
    "amnt" : 125
},
{
    "seq" : 3
    "amnt" : 25
},
{
    "seq" : 2
    "amnt" : 250
}]
```

I need to fetch objects from this array where `seq` is 2.

In Linq we have extensions in which I can put a where condition.

In Go do I need to loop through and get it using `for loop` or is there another way?

Please suggest me an optimum way.

**Note:** The json has many fields, for this example I gave only two.

I'm a new learner of Go.

Comment: what is wrong with a for loop? (Linq would have to do that under the covers anyway).

Comment: This is the 4th question shan has asked about this piece of code, and yet still refuses to refactor it to be idiomatic Go. At what point is it considered spam?

Comment: @SethHoenig sorry i didn't get you..

Comment: just stop trying to write .NET in go. Your life will be much easier.

Comment: @shan I guess what everyone is trying to say is think about what go tools offer to you instead of comparing it to other frameworks. Linq is nice but go does things differently, you have to think about other patterns than those you learned in .net, btw I think I heard someone in the go dev team once say that go tries to enforce a single correct approach to doing things, that's why you dont see 3+ types of loops in go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know about 'optimal' way to do this but here is what you can do for now to move forward:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    byt := []byte(`[{"seq": 2,"amnt": 125},{"seq": 3,"amnt": 25},{"seq": 2,"amnt": 250}]`)

    var dat []map[string]int

    if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for idx := range dat {

        if dat[idx]["seq"] == 2 {
            fmt.Println("bingo")
        }
    }
}
```

Goodluck.

**Edit:** in my first answer I assumed that you might have non-numeric values so that's why I used `interface{}` type but after @JimB suggestion I changed that to seek only `int` type, so if you have to have some `string` or any other type in you json payload the unmarshaling will fail.

Comment: you *could* make it "optimal" simply by declaring the types you need to unmarshal rather than using `interface{}`.

Comment: @JimB I assumed he might have other types in his json payload but I'll change it.

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize that the for-loop wasn't the un-optimal part. OP seems to think that because the loop requires a couple lines to write, it's somehow inferior to higher-level language features.